# Does the inductance of a power source matter when calculating the capacitance for a LC tank Circuit

Tags: inductance, resonance

I want to connect a capacitor in **parallel** to the primary of a transformer so as to resonate it (experimental purpose) and I'm powering the primary of the transformer from a Variac.

Do I need to factor in the inductance of the Variac with the inductance of the primary of the transformer when choosing the right capacitor or I only need the transformer primary coil inductance?

If I'm factoring both, does that mean that their inductance will be calculated in parallel?

Comment: Is this for a Tesla coil?

Comment: You can also call it that but at a lower frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You’re connecting a capacitor across a power source whose impedance is out of your control. So you will never be quite sure what frequency things resonate at, because to calculate the resonant circuit, you need to know the impedances. And the unknown impedance is quite complex, nonlinear, non-stationary, and may be dominating anything you can safely connect – if we’re talking of resonances at line frequencies. If the resonance would be way higher than line frequency, then the parasitic impedances may well be high enough to isolate your circuit from the rest of the power grid, but perhaps not from the other attached loads on your side of the final transformer that supplies the building.

The variac has its own variable winding inductance that’s in parallel with your tank. It also couples the line impedance somewhat to your tank, and this coupling is full (100%) when the variac is set to output voltage equal to the input voltage.

So, it will be hard to determine anything a priori from simple theory: the actual behavior of the circuit will be nonlinear and non-stationary (time-variant). You can and should give it a try, though.

For such experiments, the only dependable solution is to power your tank with either a very high impedance source, or a source with known, stable impedance.

You need either:

- a bipolar AC *current* source - high impedance by its very nature, or
- a line impedance stabilization network (LISN) that will make the line appear to have a fixed and predictable impedance across a range of frequencies that interest you.

Note that a LISN obviously can’t isolate at the fundamental of the line frequency, or there would be little energy passing through it to your load.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What size of resistor do you recommend to use with the Variac?